# Basic practice app output. Java

Tags: java, optimization, floating-point

### **Trying to do this: [practice app](http://www.codechef.com/problems/HS08TEST).**

When I test it myself it seems to work perfectly but when I upload my code I get marked incorrect(program runs but output is incorrect- no further information).

All it does is get two inputs, with and bal and check if `with 5%=0 && bal>=with+0.5`.
If both conditions are true it returns `bal-(with+0.5)`.

Also is there a more efficient (faster code execution) way of doing this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ATM {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        final float with=in.nextFloat();
        final float bal=(float) ((in.nextFloat())-(with+0.5));
        if (bal>=0 && with%5==0){
            System.out.print(bal);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you, btw, to use double instead of floats

Comment: Double should not be used for monetary values.

Comment: Can you edit your post and paste the recent code , which you tried but getting wrong answer. 
And also You have not printed the output when the balance is inefficient or when the withdrawl amount is incorrect.
And Also use change the class name to Main , if you  are submitting your code on codechef.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is incorrect, it has the wrong precision. It is clearly specified that two digits is required, and your output differs from the expected in the example:

Input:

```
30 120.00
```

Expected output:

```
89.50
```

Your output

```
89.5
```

Edit: It also probably fails the second test, since you don't output anything if the withdrawal is not a multiple of 5. It is expected to output the balance without any withdrawals.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that the autograder is expecting a new line at the end of your output, i.e. `println()` vs `print()`:

```
System.out.println(bal);
```

But as @Steinar above points out, it should be like that:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%.02f", bal));
```